# Changing an incorrect answer

Tags: discussion, comments, edits, etiquette

I recently answered a question which I had misinterpreted on my first read-through.  My answer was dead wrong, and, rightfully, it was downvoted and comments were added that explained my error.

In this case, I edited my answer and commented that the answer has been fixed, however the downvote and comments remained.  This leads me to the following question:

**What is the correct response to obsolete comments on an incorrect answer?**

- Flag the comment as obsolete immediately
- Flag the comment as obsolete after waiting some period of time
- Leave the comment alone (the edit timestamp will be newer than that comment)
- Prevent obsolete comments by deleting your incorrect answer and creating a new answer

Or is there some other more appropriate course of action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there's an obsolete comment you should flag it as such immediately.  There's no reason to leave around obsolete comments on a post.  They're only adding noise at that point.  If any of the comments are yours, you should of course just delete the comments, rather than flagging.

It's not appropriate to re-post your answer just because you want to remove a comment that is below it, even if you think that the comment is obsolete.  If you do this your answer is likely to end up flagged, and the original restored.